# What prevents this task from being long running?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, task

For testing purposes, I am using this directly inside of a razor block in a `.cshtml` page.

```
@functions{
    public class Inline
    {
        public HttpResponseBase r { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> tasks = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();

        public void Writer(HttpResponseBase response)
        {
            this.r = response;
            tasks.Add(System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () =>
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            r.Write("<span>Hello</span>");
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        }
                    }
            ));
        }
    }
}

@{
    var inL = new Inline();
    inL.Writer(Response);
}
```

I had expected it to write a span with the text "Hello" once every second. It will write "Hello" once sometimes, but not every time or even most times. Why isn't this task long running?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but just FYI, you can put `using` statements in Razor (.cshtml) files. Just prefix with `@`. So in this case, you could put `@using System.Threading.Tasks;` at the top of your file.

Comment: Sure there's no buffering going on here?

Comment: @Cameron - Can you explain a little about how buffering would affect this please?

Comment: @DanM - Thanks for that, yeah I knew using statements in razor work but that is a good point :)

Comment: @Travis: Well, I've never used Razor, but I'm assuming this is going through a server at some point -- whatever framework sits between the template and the socket might not send out each byte as soon it's generated, but rather chunks at a time (to keep things fast).

Comment: @Cameron - So does that mean the Write is getting overwritten or lost somewhere? Or that it is just sitting unwritten?

Comment: Essentially this is just C# code on the asp.net framework.

Comment: Not lost, just sitting in memory until enough bytes are generated to fill up the internal buffer. The buffer is probably flushed when the template is done being generated, but that never happens in this case. Try changing the sleep to something like 50 or 100 and watch to see if the output comes in batches. Anyway, this code doesn't smell quite right. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Cameron - Yes, this code should not smell right as it is rather hackish in its current form. I am trying to accomplish a hybrid polling process, and this is the first step of that process. On a learning curve so I am definitely not producing refined code for this approach yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing different result is because the task is running asynchronously and if the response object is completed before your task gets a chance to write on it, the taks will throw exception and it will terminate the only way you can do this is if you add Task.WaitAll() at the end of the Writer() method.

This will work but the page will not stop loading content.

```
this.r = response;
tasks.Add(System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                r.Write("<span>Hello</span>");
                r.Flush(); // this will send each write to the browser
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

));

//this will make sure that the response will stay open
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: I had tried this, but without `.Flush()`. Is there a way to wait until the page is completely loaded before running this (as the response is still writing normal content when the flush is issued - and that causes the normal content to not render).

Comment: you can create custom ActionResult and use that to make sure you are only posting the tasks content after the default result/content see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option this one uses a custom ActionResult , it first process the controller (the default result) after that is done it starts the task.

```
public class CustomActionResult:ViewResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
        var t =  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
             {

                  while (true)
                   {
                      Thread.Sleep(1000);
                      context.HttpContext.Response.Write("<h1>hello</h1>");
                      context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
                   }
            });

        Task.WaitAll(t);
    }
}
```

In your controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return new CustomActionResult();
    }
}
```